# Vitali Covering?

Tags: real-analysis

This is the problem...

Let $E$ be a subset of $R$ with $m∗(E) < ∞$, and let $K$ be a collection of compact intervals $I$ covering $E$. Show that there exists a positive constant $β$ and a finite number of disjoint intervals $I_1, . . . , I_N$ in $K$ such that

$\sum_{n=1}^N |I_n| ≥ β \cdot m∗(E)$

Is this an application of the Vitali Covering Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<\epsilon<m(E).$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\{I\}_{j\in J}$ is a countable, disjoint collection of closed, bounded intervals. Then, $\sum m(I_j)\ge m(E)$. Of course, the sum may be infinite, and if it is, the result follows. 
Otherwise, there is an integer $N$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{j=N+1}m(I_j)<\epsilon.$ Thus, $\sum^N_{j=1} m(I_j)\ge  m(E)-\epsilon$ so in this case the result also follows because we may take $\beta =1-\frac{\epsilon }{m(E))}$.

Comment: "Without loss of generality, we may assume that {I}j∈J is a countable, disjoint collection of closed, bounded intervals." I understand everything after this... but how are you getting these intervals? Because our collection K covers E in the Vitali-sense?

Comment: If any two of the intervals $[a,b], [c,d]$ in the collection are not disjoint then they intersect, in which case  their union is still  a closed  interval. If any one of the intervals so obtained is unbounded, the result is obvious. So we may replace the original collection by a collection of closed, bounded, disjoint intervals.